# Erlang arithmetic operations on ets:select result

Tags: erlang

I have an ets table which you can imagine there are two columns, "Key" and Value. Value is an integer.

When I tried:

```
 Ans = ets:select(Table_name, MS),
 Ans + 1.
```

where Ans equals to the expected Value.

I got a error:

```
 ** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
```

Can I not do any arithmetic operation on the ets:select return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the ets module spec: `select(Tab, MatchSpec) -> [Match]`, the reurn value is a list of match. If your match specification define one single integer value as return, you will receive a list of integer. In your case, it seems that this list will always have a length of 1 element, if it **must** be the case, you can write:

```
[Ans] = ets:select(Table_name, MS),
Ans + 1.
```

But beware that this code will crash if the returned list is empty or have more than 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ets:select(Table_name, MS)
```

will return result in a List.

So instead, the following would work:

```
 [Ans] = ets:select(Table_name, MS),
 Ans + 1.
```